# How to implement automatic demonstration for an iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a complete application which is running well. Now, what I want is that to demonstrate it automatically. The app will demonstrate it's each and every features for 10 sec/feature. Is there any standard way to implement it? What is the approach to implement?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a UIPageViewController and change its page like twitter did.
And shows its functionality 
Check [sample code here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[UI Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) will most likely be the best approach to this problem. And as a good side effect you get UI testing.

Up-to and including Xcode 6 UI Automation scripts are written in Javascript but as of Xcode 7 you can now write them in Swift, see [WWDC session video 406](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=406) for an intro to UI Testing.